# Unable to use ngx-cookie-service with angular 5

Tags: angular, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I am trying to upgrade my application from angular 2 to angular 5.I have updated all the dependencies and everything is building fine.But, ngx-cookie-service library is creating issues when I am trying to run my application.

In app.module.ts, I am importing the cookieservice and adding to providers array.

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
providers: [ CookieService, ApiService, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} ]
```

In my api.service.ts,

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
```

In constructor, I am instantiating it

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, 
                private _cookieService:CookiesService, 
                private router: Router) {}
```

I am using webpack to build and while running my application, I am getting this error

```
VM2645:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Object.48 (app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.89065a9ec9d93329d461.js:1)
    at eval (eval at 47 (app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:6), <anonymous>:11:17)
    at Object.47 (app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.89065a9ec9d93329d461.js:1)
    at Object.eval (eval at 0 (app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:3), <anonymous>:5:20)
    at eval (eval at 0 (app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:3), <anonymous>:11:30)
    at Object.0 (app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.89065a9ec9d93329d461.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (polyfills.89065a9ec9d93329d461.js:1)
    at app.a4460e7c733950106cd8.js:formatted:1
```

Error it is highlighting it is,

```
function(module, exports) {
        eval("export * from './cookie-service/cookie.service';\n//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64")
    },
```

I am aware it is not much to debug, still if someone else has faced this issue can help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a spelling mistake in api.service.ts.
Its not "CookiesService", its "CookieService"